# Почему выводится 0?

Tags: java

Есть код:

```
int i =0;
i = i++;
System.out.println(i);
```

Выведет на консоль 0.

**Вопрос, почему - 0 ?**

Comment: Почитать нужно про ++ :)

Да и что за бред

> i = i++;

просто

>i++;

Comment: я знаю отлично про i++ ++i ,в чем отличия и все дела , этот вопрос видел где-то в тестах , на самом деле это разрыв мозга , так как по логике должно быть 1 !! Это какой-то баг компилятора !! Я прекрасно понимаю что никто так не будет писать код , но все же ....

Comment: Почитайте правила приоритетов Java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: php:

    function post_inc(&$n) {
      $r = $n;
      $n++;
      return $r;
    }
    $i = 0;
    $i = post_inc($i);
    echo $i;

Так, наверно, более наглядно. Пардон за php, надеюсь поймете)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

- *`Offtop` насчет такой конструкции в `C++`*

> **Этот код может вывести 0, 1 и, вообще говоря, все что угодно.** `i = i++` по стандарту - это `undefined behavior`.

- Есть стандарт, который определяет такое понятие как [**sequence point.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) Так вот, разбор данного выражения в свете этих самых `sequence points` предполагает двукратное изменение значения `i` между двумя `sequence point'ами`. Что по стандарту ведет к [**undefined behavior.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)
- Подробнее можно почитать [**здесь.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

---

- В `Java` все проще - данный код однозначно соответствует следующему коду. Подробнее - [**тут.**](http://skeletoncoder.blogspot.com/2006/09/java-tutorials-i-i.html)

  ```
  int temp = i; // temp = 0
  i++; // i = 1
  i = temp; // i = 0
  ```

Comment: иногда за ваши ответы одного плюса кажется мало!

Comment: Поддержим массовостью плюсования.

Comment: А разве операция присваивания не является сама точкой следования?

Answer (score 7):

> i= i++;

Сначала производится инкремент, который увеличивает i на единицу, но возвращает ноль. 
Затем, возвращенный инкрементом ноль присваивается i.

Comment: int i=5;
    i = i++;
    System.out.println(i);

вернет 5

Comment: может так понятней будет:

    int IncrementI()
    {
       int result = i;
       i = i+1;
       return result;
    }
    int i = 0;
    i = IncrementI();

Answer (score 2):

```
i=i++
```

Означает, что сначала производится операция присвоения, а потом инкремент - поэтому у вас "ноль".

Надо писать или просто `i++` или на худой конец `i=++i`

Comment: прочитай внимательно что ты написал , ..производится операция присвоения , А ПОТОМ ИНКРЕМЕНТ ... инкремент должен же произойти , после присваивания,но нифина

Comment: А какая разница?  

>сначала производится операция присвоения, а потом инкремент

Ведь вывод в консоль происходит после инкременента.

Comment: Так почему не выполнился инкремент? Он же перед выводом.

Comment: > Производится операция присвоения, а потом инкремент... инкремент должен же произойти после присваивания, но ни фига.

Не совсем так. Постинкремент увеличивает `i` на единицу и возвращает свое состояние до инкремента. Поэтому в `i` присваивается `0`.

Comment: int j = 0; 
i = j++;
sysout(j);
Выведет 1 !! ну и ?

Comment: @Playmate надо i выводить, а не j, увидите 0.

Comment: если так рассуждать , то :
int i = 0;
i++;
sysout(i);
i будет равным 0 ? конечно нет , будет 1 !!! смысл тогда в инкременте

Comment: @Playmate вопрос в этом как раз и заключается. Что присвоение постинкремента ведет себя не очевидно.

Comment: прочитайте наконец ответ тов. @xolcman